# How can I reorder the column sequence of my DataTable in my Django App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatables

I am doing a ajax request to pass some data from Views.py to the HTML file and render it using DataTables() javascript library.

The problem I am facing is that the displayed datatable is not following the column order that I would like to.

I don´t know if the solution is to reorder the json data that the datatable receives or to use some functionallity of DataTables().

What should be the best solution to reorder the table´s column? And how can I apply it to the code bellow?

Views.py

```
...
def test_table(request):

    data_pers = {
            'Product':request.GET.get('Product'),
            'Length':request.GET.get('Length'),
            'Cod':request.GET.get('cod'),
            'partnumbetr':'42367325'
            }

    return JsonResponse({'data_prod':data_prod})
```

...

HTML

```
...
$.get('{% url "test_table" %}',
    {Product:Product,Length:Length,Cod:Cod},
    function (data_prod) {
    var data_json_prod=data_prod['data_prod'];
    var data_array_prod = [];
    var arr_prod = $.map(data_json_prod, function(el) { return el });
    data_array_prod.push(arr_prod);

    $('#id_prod').DataTable({
        destroy: true,                                      
        data:data_array_prod,
    });
...
```

Comment: Define the column definitions in Datatable options as outlined in docs

Comment: Hi charlietfl.. How can I do that? I don´t have much expertise in javascript

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns

Comment: not working: I am trying  " columns: [{ title: "Var1",targets:2}] "

Comment: to put the 3 column in the first column to be displayed